# Is it ok to re-slope one of my gutters to another gutter?

Tags: water, roof, gutters

Right now, on one side of my roof, I have two gutters that come together at an inside corner. Each gutter goes to the edge of the house with a downspout, which would mean that the inside corner is the highest spot of the two gutters.

I would like to remove one of the downspouts and re-slope that gutter to feed into the other gutter. So then one end of the gutter would be the highest spot as opposed to the inside corner.

Would this be feasible? Could my gutters hold that amount of water?

Comment: Have you actually measured the pitch in the existing arrangement?

Comment: To find out what information?

Comment: My experience is that roofers want to attach the gutters level with the horizontal fascia. and rely of partially filling the gutter to get the water to the downspout...YMMV

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed that roofers would do that. Doesn't seem right. But my gutters are sloped well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

Generally, the number and size of the downspouts is sized to handle a certain water volume. So if two downspouts were installed, then they probably can't handle just two.

Also, the gutters have to be pitched at down 1/2 inch for every 10 feet. If your facia board isn't tall enough to handle that slope for the entire length, then you need two downspouts.

Comment: I'll have to do some math to figure out potential volume from the roof and the volume the gutters can hold. Not sure where to look for that information so if anyone has a quick link it would be appreciated.